# jquery detect when iframe is load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I try to use this script to check an iframe after i press button "click", it's works only in Google Chrome. In firefox and IE is refreshing continues.

```
<button type="button"  data-toggle="modal" href="#procesare"  id='click' class="btn-xs  btn btn-success"></button>
<iframe style="display:none;" src="" id="actualizare"></iframe>
<script>

        $('#actualizare').load(function(){
    location.reload();
});
$(function(){

    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        $('#actualizare').attr('src', 'myurl.com'); 

    });
});

</script>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kPQ2M/

Comment: `$('#actualizare').ready(function(){` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @KevinB it's .load i edit it now

Comment: @MilchePatern Just ignor it, i delete it

Comment: if the refreshing doesn't continue, then your code actually isn't working. There's nothing in your code that would stop the refreshing. `e.preventDefault();` is causing a syntax error.

Comment: @KevinB How i can prevent ? Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/kPQ2M/ (open in ff)

Comment: by unbinding the load event so that it'l stop refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

To try what Kevin B is suggesting, remove your load event from the iframe when your button is clicked.

```
$('#click').on('click', function(){
    $('#actualizare').off('load'); 
    $('#actualizare').attr('src', 'myurl.com'); 

});
```

Comment: I resolve it, it was from iframe because src was empty firefox was detect it like was ready document (allready loaded) jquery was refresh it. <iframe style="display:none;" src="empty.html" id="actualizare"></iframe><script>
$(function(){
    
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        $('#actualizare').attr('src', 'url'); 
         $( "#procesare" ).toggle("fast");
 $('#actualizare').ready(function(){
 location.reload();
});
    });
});
</script>